# React JS send post request to Springboot Rest Server and get error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, post, axios, cors

I am hosting my React app in localhost:3000, and hosting my SpringBoot RESTServer at localhost:8080, tried to send a post request to that server and got following error:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/employees' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

but i already put Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my code:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/employees', params, {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'mode': 'no-cors'
      }
    }
    )
```

API tested with postman and it worked.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the `CORS` issue. You can google it and acquire lots of explanation which will tell you why the request is blocked when you call an api through the browser.

Basically, the `CORS` issue of **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** could be solved by setting you api endpoint. For `sprint-boot` api, you can try this two way.

1. Add `@CrossOrigin` onto the specific path controller

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@GetMapping("/employees")
public Employees getEmployees() {
    // ...
}
```

2. Set the global `CORS` configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                // Allow all origin to call your api
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can reference [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) for more clearly `CORS` settings in spring-boot.